# Function pointer to friend operator overload for use with bind

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, bind, function-pointers

The end goal is the following: I want to be able to use `for_each` with `operator<<`.  I realized I can just use `ostream_iterator` but I would like to see if it is possible without it.

Some example code so you can get an idea of what I want to do:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using std::bind;
using std::ref;
using std::placeholders::_1;
using std::for_each;
using std::ostream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

class C {
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        C() : x(0) { }
        C(int x) : x(x) { }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const C& c);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const C& c) {
    return out << c.x << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<C> v;
    v.push_back(C(1));
    v.push_back(C());

    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), bind(&ostream::operator<<, ref(cout), _1));

    return 0;
}
```

A thing I have unsuccessfully tried (above):

`bind(static_cast<ostream& (ostream::*)(ostream&, const C&)>(&ostream::operator<<), ref(cout), _1)`

Comment: Why/when is for_each "better" as for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're specifying the wrong `operator<<`; you've specified `ostream::operator<<`, but your `operator<<` is free i.e. `::operator<<`.

This works in your current program:

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), bind(&::operator<<, ref(cout), _1));
```

However if you add any more free `operator<<`s then it will fail again, since `bind` cannot decide which `operator<<` is meant.  In that case you would have to specify through an explicit specialization:

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), bind<ostream&(*)(ostream&, const C&)>(&::operator<<, ref(cout), _1));
```

Equivalently, you could use `static_cast<ostream&(*)(ostream&, const C&)>(&::operator<<)`.

The problem is that the `<<` in `std::cout << c` could be either a free operator or a member operator, and there's no way to know which a priori.  `ostream_iterator` works by generating code that allows the compiler to decide how to evaluate the expression; similarly if you use a lambda or just a range for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a lambda, as in:

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](C const& c){ cout << c; });
```

Personally, I prefer to use `for_each` when my intention is to visit every element in the sequence.

Comment: I like the use of lambdas for this - they allow to state the explicit use of `C::operator<<` in a much more obvious way than the `bind` / member function pointer casting combination.

Answer (score 1):

Is here any problem?

```
for (auto c :v) cout<<c;
```

or here:

```
for (const auto& c :v) cout<<c;
```

or here:

```
for (C const& c :v) cout<<c;
```

Comment: Those are fine, I wanted to use `for_each` (note my example is an oversimplified version).